# Solving a non-elementary integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$L=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}\frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}dx$$
How can one approach this integral? I've tried inserting an extra variable to perform Feynman's trick but it just complicates it more.Kindly give a few hints on how to solve this.

Comment: Would you care to explain how you attempted to use Feynman trick? Putting up all of your scratch work beyond a simple problem statement will improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: perform the substitution $x=\epsilon u$ so that $\epsilon$ only appears inside the integrand and not in the bounds. Then you can move the limit inside the integral (be sure to justify this step with your favorite convergence theorem).

Comment: There is the small problem that this substitution makes the situation worse and not better. However this can be easily fixed :)

Comment: @NinadMunshi er... yes, I got that backwards, whoops! Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Term-by-term integration of the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)...  (Conveniently, there's only one disk or annulus of convergence with inner radius $0$ and outer radius $\infty$ **and** the pole at $x = 0$ is simple.)

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{(x-1)^2}}{x} &= \frac{\mathrm{e}}{x} - 2 \mathrm{e}+3 \mathrm{e}x - \frac{10 \mathrm{e} x^2}{3} + \frac{19 \mathrm{e} x^3}{6} + \cdots  \\
\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \; \frac{\mathrm{e}}{x} &{}- 2 \mathrm{e}+3 \mathrm{e}x - \frac{10 \mathrm{e} x^2}{3} + \frac{19 \mathrm{e} x^3}{6} + \cdots \,\mathrm{d}x \\
{} &= \mathrm{e}\ln(2) - 2 \mathrm{e}\epsilon + \frac{9 \mathrm{e} \epsilon^2}{2} - \frac{70 \mathrm{e} \epsilon^3}{9} + \frac{95 \mathrm{e} \epsilon^4}{8} + \cdots  \\
&\underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}{\longrightarrow} \mathrm{e} \ln 2  \text{.}
\end{align*}